# Netbeans not generating javadoc properly

Tags: java, javadoc, netbeans-7

This is an example of class that I have written for my project and it's documented in italian:

```
/**
 * Eccezione da lanciare nel caso si verifichi un guasto al motore.
 * Eredita da <a  href="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html">
 * java.lang.Exception </a>.
 * 
 * @author Ramy Al Zuhouri
 * @version 1.0
 */
package truckingCompany.utilities;

public class EngineFailureException extends Exception
{
    /**
     * Viene chiamato il costruttore della superclasse Exception, con un 
     * messaggio che descrive l' accaduto.
     */
    public EngineFailureException()
    {
        super("Guasto al motore durante il rientro alla base");
    }
}
```

But there is a problem generating javadoc: the upper part of comments aren't seen in the html page generated.
So all this part:

```
/*
 * Eccezione da lanciare nel caso si verifichi un guasto al motore.
 * Eredita da <a  href="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html">
 * java.lang.Exception </a>.
 * 
 * @author Ramy Al Zuhouri
 * @version 1.0
 */
```

Isn't shown in the page.How to force netbeans to include also these comments?

Answer (score 3):

It's because that isn't a javadoc comment. Javadoc comments look like:

```
/**
*
*
*/
```

Whereas yours is:

```
/*
*
*
*/
```

Notice the difference in the first line? If you add another `*` to the top line to make it `/**` it should work fine.

For more information on comment types in Java [read here.](http://www.roseindia.net/java/language/java-comments.shtml)

Comment: Sorry, it's just a copy-and-paste mistake.It doesn't work even if I put two '*' characters.I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting it above the class instead of above the package?